# Angular: Why would a http call work from in ngOnInit and not from a click event? (Something to do with caching)

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs

In my angular app I have a simple service set up to make calls to the server. and I have injected the service into a component. If I call one of it's methods directly in the component's ngOnInit() method it works fine and the expected response is received from the back end. If I call the very same service method by clicking a button in the component I get a http error in the console log:

```
VM460:1 GET https://myurl/getUserNumber net::ERR_FAILED
   message: "Http failure response for https://myurl/getUserNumber: 0 Unknown Error"
   {
      ...
      name: "HttpErrorResponse"
      ok: false
      status: 0
      statusText: "Unknown Error"
   }
```

If I understand it correctly the problem is that the server does not like the request or something like that. But what is the difference between the first and the second http call? What am I missing? Thanks!

```
// service method
getUserNumber(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(url.getUserNumber);
}

// component
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {

    private userNumber$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getUserNumber()
            .subscribe( (user: User) => this.userNumber$.next(user.number));
    }

    getUserNumber(): void {
        this.dataService.getUserNumber()
            .subscribe( (user: User) => this.userNumber$.next(user.number));
    }
}

 <!-- button to call the service method from template which is not working -->
 <button (click)="getUserNumber()">GET</button>
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I don't *think* the issue is cors related - the app can be viewed at *myurl.com* and the http calls go to *myurl.com/getwhatever*. I am updating an existing app which makes  ajax queries with jQuery and I'm using the same environment/setup etc, just with angular instead of jquery - nothing else is different in that regard (as far as I can see).

To try and strip things back to basics as much as possible I made a fresh angular app with just a very basic service which is called from the app.component.ts as below. `ngOnInit()` works fine and the time and user info are displayed. Clicking the button for `getTime()` works and updates the screen, clicking the button for `getUserNumber()` fails as usual. (the time thing is just to see if I could spot anything about Observables that I was missing with the http part taken out... I'm not too hot with rxjs)

The full log out put is here: https://pastebin.com/v6SmzHnn

Details of the error are here: https://pastebin.com/FkxF58ea

*app.component.ts*

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    user$: Observable<{}>;
    time$: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getTime();
        this.getUserNumber();
    }

    getUserNumber(): void {
        this.user$ = this.api.getUserNumber();
    }

    getTime(): void {
        this.time$ = this.api.getTime();
    }

}
```

*api.service.ts*

```
export class ApiService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public getUserNumber(): Observable<{}> {
        return this.http.get<{}>(url.getUserNumber);
    }

    public getTime(): Observable<string> {
        const today = new Date();
        const time = today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() + ':' + today.getSeconds();
        return of(time);
    }
}
```

template

```
<button (click)="getUser()">Get User</button>
<button (click)="getTime()">Get time</button>

<div>{{ time$ | async }}</div>
<div><pre>{{ (user$ | async) | json }}</pre></div>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I am using a manifest file to cache the application for offline usage - this seems to be the source of the problem - there are no errors when the manifest is not included. The old jquery app also uses a manifest so I'm not sure why it breaks angular but at least I can forget about rxjs, cors etc...

Comment: Status 0 errors are usually from CORS issues.

Comment: Is there some reason I would only run into this when clicking the button?

Comment: @Rectangular - it is already there

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it. Do you have any HTTP interceptors?

Comment: @Shane Can you please try button click after commenting code inside ngOnInit() method. If it works after commenting ngOnInit() code then check your API implementation. Most probably you should find something fishy in your API.

Comment: No interceptor and commenting the ngoninit does not help, error occurs whenever going the getUserNumber() method is called whether from ngoninit or from button

Comment: Check the network for CORS pre-flight OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Your code here looks absolutely fine, there is something else that causes error. Open network tab in developer tools and tell us what is happening there

Answer (score 1):

You're calling subscribe each time you click. It's a new subscription and the old one is still "hot". Try using `take` in order to make the cal and end the sub properly. Otherwise you'll have x number of subscriptions.

```
getUserNumber(): void {
    this.dataService.getUserNumber().pipe(
       take(1)
    ).subscribe( (user: User) => {
       console.log(user); // make sure you're getting a response from dataService
       this.userNumber$.next(user.number)
    });
}
```

Also, make the call to `getUserNumber()` in ngOnInit so you don't have 2 subscriptions. (best practice + makes troubleshooting easier)

```
public ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserNumber();
}
```

Comment: I guess he does wants to make another http request when he clicks at the button

Comment: This will call his API each time. `this.dataService.getUserNumber()` should return an observable which waits for a response each time it's hit.

Comment: Thanks for that @Ben Racicot, unfortunately I'm still running into the http error when I go through component's getUserNumber() method. The call in ngOnInit was just to there to see if it worked that way

Comment: Oh! Then you're def having issues with the endpoint. Can you get us more info on the error? Maybe Postman? Also, make sure to remove the subscribe in ngOnit so you're using the same method to make troubleshooting easier. It could be dying because there is a live subscription... Did u try my recommendations?

Comment: I took the call out of ngoninit altogether so that the service method is only called when the button is clicked, however I'm still getting the error. I guess it is something subscription related :    
     defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:15724
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:15772
next @ core.js:17771
schedulerFn @ core.js:13515
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134

Comment: Try it without the `next` call and see if you get what you expect back from `dataService`. The next call may be the cause? Also you have `BehaviorSubject<string>('')` but you're sending it `user.number`. Is that a number?

Comment: Yes the number is a string in reality. Next, I will try without the next... In the morning. Thanks a lot!